# make div disappear 850px from bottom only when screen is less than 600px wide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this function that makes my div disappear 850 px from the bottom of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 850) {
    $('.guide').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('.guide').show();
  }
});
</script>
```

but i'd like this to ONLY happen if the screen is 600px wide or less, how can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried `&& $(document).width() < 600`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).width()`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 850 && $(window).width() <= 600) {
    $('.guide').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('.guide').show();
  }
});
</script>
```